# Python - I'm trying to create a simple web scraper for the steam market

Tags: python, steam

so I'm in school and have finished up with my Python introductory class and I decided to use my skills to try and make something useful, so I wanted to make a script to scrape a Steam market webpage and notify me when an item is listed for at or below a desired price. I'm kind of stuck and hope I can get any tips to help me out. I am using urllib2 and BeautifulSoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
import time



item = str(raw_input('Please enter the item you are looking for(Exact URL): '))
price = str(raw_input('Please enter the price you want to buy the item at: '))

print('Searching for item at that price....\n' + item)

market = urlopen(item)

def getPrices(market,desiredPrice):
    while True:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(market)
        prices = soup.findAll('span',{'class':'market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee'})

        """
        So now my logic assumed I should do something like;

        if desiredPrice in prices:
            print('found item at the desired price!')
            return link_to_item

        """

        print('Searching...')
        time.sleep(20)


getPrices(market, price)
```

For testing I am using this steam market link: https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29

And the span that contains the prices of each item on the front page is class='market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee'

Bottom line problem:
I cannot seem to get just the data from within each span tag; I want to just grab the prices as floats and put them into a list and then I would be able to sort through that; and Then I would be able to compare them to the desired price and find anything below the desired price.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what problem you are having

Comment: I cannot seem to get just the data from within each span tag; I want to just grab the prices as floats and put them into a list and then I would be able to sort through that; and Then I would be able to compare them to the desired price and find anything below the desired price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of text in those spans. If you filter it out you should be fine.

```
>>> [i.text.strip() for i in prices]
[u'Sold!', u'\xa5 33.69', u'\xa5 33.69', u'Sold!', u'\xa5 33.69', u'\xa5 33.69', u'\xa5 33.69', u'\xa5 33.69', u'\xa5 33.69', u'\xa5 33.69']
```

There is a yen sign in there, you could take that out too unless you need currency information.

To get only numbers I'd do:

```
prices = [i.text.strip() for i in prices]
prices =  [float(k) for k in [''.join([j for j in i if j in '0123456789.']) for i in prices] if k]
if min(prices)< desiredPrice:
```

Bear in mind that you'd need to `float(desiredPrice)` first and make sure you are reading web data within the loop. Currently you will check exactly the same data every 20 seconds!

Comment: Thanks! This helped me greatly and I have it functioning now! Just still fiddling around with grabbing the link associated to each price